# Bindings not firing on Interface

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, binding, flex-spark

I have an interface `IBaseInterface` and a class `BaseClass`.

When I refer to `BaseClass` via the `IBaseInterface` type the bindings with event names won't fire. However the normal binding *(without event name)* fires.

If I refer to `BaseClass` with `Object` or `BaseClass` types all is OK and the bindings fire.

**IBaseInterface:**

```
[Event(name="propTwoChanged", type="flash.events.Event")]
[Event(name="propThreeChanged", type="flash.events.Event")]

[Bindable]

public interface IBaseInterface extends IEventDispatcher{

    function get propOne() :Number;
    function set propOne(value:Number) :void;

    [Bindable(event="propTwoChanged")]
    function get propTwo() :Number;

    [Bindable(event="propThreeChanged")]
    function get propThree() :Number;

}
```

**BaseClass:**

```
[Event(name="propTwoChanged", type="flash.events.Event")]
[Event(name="propThreeChanged", type="flash.events.Event")]

[Bindable]

public class BaseClass extends EventDispatcher implements IBaseInterface{

    private var _propOne:Number = 0;
    public function get propOne() :Number{
        return _propOne;
    }
    public function set propOne(value:Number) :void{
        _propOne = value;
        dispatchEvent(new Event('propTwoChanged'));
        dispatchEvent(new Event('propThreeChanged'));
    }

    [Bindable(event="propTwoChanged")]
    public function get propTwo() :Number{
        return propOne * 2;
    }

    [Bindable(event="propThreeChanged")]
    public function get propThree() :Number{
        return propOne / 2;
    }

}
```

So, to clarify the problem:

- `propTwo` and `propThree` bindings on `IBaseInterface` do not fire.
- `propOne` binding is OK, this does not have an event name.
- The problem only occurs when accessing via the interface, other types are OK.

Comment: So far on this I have double checked that all the metadata on the interface matches the class, and I have even extended `IEventDispatcher`

Comment: The real use case for this will be where I have `IModelBase` and a lot of different models that all implement `IModelBase` in different ways. That way I can reuse the same view and just switch out the model as required.

Comment: I find the whole construction a bit strange anyways: there's a lot of redundancy there. You're repeating the exact same metadata from the implementation in the interface and there's a class-wide [Bindable] tag that is overridden (maybe?) by tags with custom events. Also by putting the metadata on the interface, you're actually already saying how the implementations should be implemented.

Comment: @RIAstar: I think the real use case makes more sense, I also extend `IBaseInterface` and `BaseClass` so the redundancy is reduced. Also I only reproduced the metadata in the interface because I read that I needed to for the bindings to work.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand the use case. Since these properties are Bindable, this is a model whose properties are going to be shown in a view. If view A and B only have access to the properties exposed by the interface, they can only show the same data, hence they are the same views. There's a logic I can't quite fathom there ;) If views A and B are only supposed to look differently, but behave the same way, then you should look at Spark skinning.

Comment: @RIAstar: It's not multiple views, it's multiple models. All the models hold the same data but it comes from different sources. The user can switch between the data sources at runtime, so this switches the models

Comment: I understand how data can come from different data sources, but I don't understand how that makes the model any different. The model should always be the same, no matter what the source. If you'd make an interface for service stubs for instance, and the implementations would approach these various data sources, that I would understand.

Comment: @RIAstar: Then I suppose it's more than just a simple model, it's an abstraction layer which actually gets the data from the source and not just a presentation model.

Comment: Then I guess the way to go is to separate the model from the data-fetching logic. Maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9256865/how-to-separate-remote-object-and-interface-in-flash-builder-flex/9258177#9258177

Comment: As RIAStar mentioned, your code may not be working as expected because of the class level [Bindable] may be interfering w/the two bindings at the property level. What happens if you move that class level [Bindable] to property 1 (and keep everything else the same).

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but could you show some code from the view side?

Comment: @SunilD.: I don't think it's interfering, the event based bindings override the class level binding. I tested anyway, it has the same problem.

Comment: @AmyBlankenship: There's nothing specific in the view, it's just testing code at the moment. only 3 labels and a button to change the propOne value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found 2 options to fix this:

### Option 1

Defining a single `[Bindable(event="...")]` metadata on the interface (not on the function signatures), and then dispatching a single event to update all properties on the interface.

**`IBaseInterface`:**

```
[Event(name="updateBindings", type="flash.events.Event")]
[Bindable(event="updateBindings")]
public interface IBaseInterface extends IEventDispatcher{

    function get propOne() :Number;
    function set propOne(value:Number) :void;

    function get propTwo() :Number;

    function get propThree() :Number;

}
```

**`BaseClass`:**

```
[Event(name="updateBindings", type="flash.events.Event")]
[Bindable(event="updateBindings")]
public class BaseClass extends EventDispatcher implements IBaseInterface{

    private var _propOne:Number = 0;
    public function get propOne() :Number{
        return _propOne;
    }
    public function set propOne(value:Number) :void{
        _propOne = value;
        dispatchEvent(new Event('updateBindings'));
    }

    public function get propTwo() :Number{
        return propOne * 2;
    }

    public function get propThree() :Number{
        return propOne / 2;
    }

}
```

This is a little clumsy I think, if there are a lot of properties or a lot of listeners in the view then it would be too resource intensive.

---

### Option 2

Defining a single `[Bindable]` *(without event)* on the interface, and then from the class directly dispatching a `PropertyChangeEvent`.

**`IBaseInterface`:**

```
[Bindable]
public interface IBaseInterface extends IEventDispatcher{

    function get propOne() :Number;
    function set propOne(value:Number) :void;

    function get propTwo() :Number;

    function get propThree() :Number;

}
```

**`BaseClass`:**

```
[Bindable]
public class BaseClass extends EventDispatcher implements IBaseInterface{

    private var _propOne:Number = 0;
    public function get propOne() :Number{
        return _propOne;
    }
    public function set propOne(value:Number) :void{
        _propOne = value;
        dispatchEvent(new PropertyChangeEvent(PropertyChangeEvent.PROPERTY_CHANGE, true, true, PropertyChangeEventKind.UPDATE, 'propTwo'));
        dispatchEvent(new PropertyChangeEvent(PropertyChangeEvent.PROPERTY_CHANGE, true, true, PropertyChangeEventKind.UPDATE, 'propThree'));
    }

    public function get propTwo() :Number{
        return propOne * 2;
    }

    public function get propThree() :Number{
        return propOne / 2;
    }

}
```

This way is best I think, it is less intensive than option 1 because only the required properties are updated. It also cleans up the code, most metadata can be removed from the class and interface.

Comment: Interesting exercise. +1 for testing and sharing

Comment: Did you try not marking the entire Class as Bindable? The Flex compiler is generating some code for you that is probably interfering, and I bet you could get exactly the behavior you want if you removed that Bindable metadata.